# Will spark wholetextfiles pick partially created file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, sparkcore

I am using Spark wholeTextFiles API to read the files from source folder and load it to hive table.

File are arriving at source folder from a remote server. File are of huge size like 1GB-3GB. SCP of the files is taking quite a while.

If i launch the spark job and file is being SCPd to the source folder and process is halfway, will spark pick the file?

If spark pick the file when it is halfway, it would be a problem since it would ignore rest of the content of the file.

Comment: how are the files being written to hdfs?  For example, I use Sqoop to import data from an external database to hdfs, and it writes to a temporary directory first, and as a last step moves the files out of temporary into the target directory.

Comment: spark source folder receiving the files using scp. Source folder is on the node where spark was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible way to resolve:

1. At end of each file copy, SCP ZERO-kb file to indicate that SCP complete.
2. In spark job, when you do sc.wholeTextFiles(...), pick only those file names that has zero kb corresponding file - using map.

So, Here's code to check if correspondidng `.ctl` files are present in src folder.

```
val fr = sc.wholeTextFiles("D:\\DATA\\TEST\\tempstatus")

// Get only .ctl file
val temp1 = fr.map(x => x._1).filter(x => x.endsWith(".ctl"))

// Identify corresponding REAL-FILEs - without .ctl suffix
val temp2 = temp1.map(x => (x.replace(".ctl", ""),x.replace(".ctl", "")))

val result = fr
  .join(xx)
  .map{
    case (_, (entry, x)) => (x, entry)
  }
```

... Process rdd `result` as required.

The rdd `temp2` is changed from `RDD[String]` to `RDD[String, String]` - for `JOIN` operation. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you are SCPing the files in to the source folder; and then spark is reading from that folder; it might happen that, half-written files are picked by spark, as SCP might take some time to copy.

That will happen for sure.

Your task would be - how not to write directly in that source folder - so that Spark doesn't pick incomplete files.

Possible way to resolve:

1. At end of each file copy, SCP ZERO-kb file to indicate that SCP complete.
2. In spark job, when you do `sc.wholeTextFiles(...)`, pick only those file names that has zero kb corresponding file - using map.

Comment: Your answer seems helpful. Could you please give me an example of map transformation to pick corresponding file with zero kb file. My understanding is that to use filter instead of map.